# Enumerate mounted volumes on iOS

Tags: ios, sd-card, volume, mount

Following code works fine on MacOS, but return empty list on iOS with SanDisk «SanDisk iXpand» flash drive:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLVolumeNameKey, NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey, nil];
NSArray *urls = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:keys options:0];
NSLog(@«%@», urls); // print «null»
for (NSURL *url in urls) {
  NSError *error;
  NSNumber *isRemovable;
  NSString *volumeName;
  [url getResourceValue:&isRemovable forKey:NSURLVolumeIsRemovableKey error:&error];
  if ([isRemovable boolValue]) {
    [url getResourceValue:&volumeName forKey:NSURLVolumeNameKey error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", volumeName);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get list of mounted volumes on iOS?

Comment: Since iOS apps are sandboxes you can not access file outside of your apps sandbox. The mounted volumes are outside the apps sandbox and there for failing. Thus unless SanDisk is providing a SDK for there card reader you will not be able to access it. Because accessing accessories requires the MFI program license.

Comment: You are not checking for errors and reporting them.  Start doing that and see if anything useful is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't support mounting volumes or accessing them, which is why you are not getting a list of mounted volumes.

The iXpand device is accessed only through the SanDisk app.

Comment: check out FileBrowser app it can access any connects flash drive without using ScanDisk app

Comment: Things have changed in 5 years